# Limit the number of tabs and windows in Firefox

Tags: firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

For a user that won't stop opening windows and tabs, and never close anything, then complain that the computer is too slow, I'm looking for a way to set a maximum number of tabs, application wide (not per window) in Firefox. Ideally, something that would enforce every tab to live in the same window, so that he can clearly understand where things are.
The user in question has no notion of extensions, applications settings, or anything..

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of Firefox extensions to limit the number of tabs:

- [Limit Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rudolf-fernandes/)
- [Max Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/max-tabs-web-ext/)
- [Tab Limiter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-limiter/)

That said, I've not tried these, so check them yourself for security, such as the information they access, and also for effectiveness.

You might also want to [limit the number of processes](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/performance-settings), which could have a greater effect on system demands.

Of course, a *knowledgeable* user could change these settings, but from your description, that does not pertain.

Comment: the problem is that he will accidentally open new windows, and tabs inside that new window..  I'm looking for something really rigid..

Comment: FWIW, while the extension "Limit Tabs" won't limit the number of windows, it at least seems very rigid when it comes to limiting the number of tabs.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to use the add-on
[Auto Tab Discard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard/),
which doesn’t close the tabs – it just suspends them so they’re not hogging memory
when not in use.

This add-on lets you set up rules to automatically suspend browser tabs that are
left open, so this will not interfere with the guy's work, but will avoid
the slow-down.

Suspended tabs are slightly dimmed and have a grey dot on them to make them easy
to distinguish.

[image]